# Download an uploaded django .docx file

Tags: python, django

I have a website where i upload a .docx file and then the users can download the document.

my model

```py
    class Files(model.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      doc_File = models.FileField(upload_to='media')
```

my View

```py
    def Uploaded(request):
      file = Files.objects.filter('doc_File')  
      return render(request, 'uploaded_files.html', {'file':file})
```

urls

```py
    path('file, views.Uploaded, name='file'),
```

my html page

```
{% block content %}

    <h4>Download Document Below</h4>
     {% for f in file %}
    <a href="{% url 'f.url' %}" Download>{{f.url}}</a>
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am not able to download the .docx file
could anyone help pliz ....

Answer (score 0):

Youre return is not right, try

```
data = open(doc.name, "rb").read() //doc.name is youre filefield from your model
return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
```

In template:

```
 <a href="{%  url "//youre url in url.py to the download view" %}>
```

Comment: How should I call the File in the html template

Comment: see updated answer, just link to youre url

Comment: Should I pass in ID for each object?

Comment: Yep pass in parameters in the url if you like, then in your view you can get the right object.doc